Recovering a linear ODE w/ constant coefficients given the roots of the auxiliary equation
I'm solving the following question related to linear ordinary differential equations with constant coeffcients in preparation for my upcoming exam:
The auxiliary equation $P(m) = 0$
of a 5th
order ordinary differential equation of the form $()=0$
yields the following solutions:
$_1 = 2$;
$_2 = 6$
($m_2$
has algebraic multiplicity equal to 2
);
$_3 = 8+\sqrt{6}$; and
$_4 = 8−\sqrt{6}$.
What is the differential equation?
I really cannot see how to answer it. I know that, if the question were framed the other way around, I could use linear-algebraic methods to turn the differential equation into a polynomial equation. But this is not the case here. Any help?
Edit
Here is the solution to my question: the above roots imply that the auxiliary polynomial, written as a product of linear terms, is $$P(m) = (m - 2)(m - 6)^2(m - 8 - \sqrt{6}i)(m - 8 + \sqrt{6}i).$$ Multiplying the factors out gives a polynomial of degree 5 each term of which corresponds to a power of the differential operator (i.e. $P(m) \iff P(D)y$).

Hint - forget differential equations, treat this as a polynomial question. What does a corollary to the fundamental theorem of algebra say?

Any complex root of a polynomial with real coefficients comes with its complex conjugate? Not sure how this is relevant though.

By 'complex' I meant 'non-real'. Real numbers are also complex numbers of course.

@LutzLehmann sorry I hadn't realised how badly-copied my formulas were. I think the rooted imaginary parts were the only almost-non-understandable pieces of notation, the rest should be fine.

Hint:

 If $a$ is a zero of a polynomial, then $x-a$ is a factor of that polynomial.

Hint 2:

 If $z$ is a complex zero, then so too is $\bar{z}.$

Sketch of solution:

 Use the above hints, and use the fact that any polynomial can be written as a product of linear factors. Translate powers into derivatives, and you have found an ODE that meets the conditions needed.


Thank you I think I've got it! The above roots imply that the polynomial written as a product of linear factors is $$(m - 2)(m - 6)^2(m - 8 - \sqrt{6}i)(m - 8 + \sqrt{6}i),$$ which once expanded gives a 5th-degree polynomial each of whose $m$ terms corresponds to a power of the differential operator (i.e. $P(m) \leftrightarrow P(D)y$). Correct?
